# É possível utilizar o Sqlite3 no Android usando o aplicativo QPython3?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Estou tentando criar uma tabela:

```
import sqlite3

def criar_tab_contato(conexao):

   cursor = conexao.cursor()

   sql = """
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contato(
   nome text,
   telefone text,
   senha text
   );
   """

   cursor.execute(sql)


conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.contato")

criar_tab_contato(conexao)

conexao.close()
```

Mas apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
 /data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/Download/.last_tmp.py" && exit
lated/0/Download/.last_tmp.py" && exit      <
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/.last_tmp.py", line 18, in <module>
    conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.contato")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
1|whyred:/ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível a partir da versão 1.0 do QPython, porém, você precisa definir onde salvar o arquivo. O erro está indicando que você não tem permissão pra salvar no lugar onde você tentou:

```
conexao = sqlite3.connect("/storage/emulated/0/Download/banco.contato")
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!